# spring cloud stream ibm qm binder implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

is there a cloud stream ibm qm binder for spring cloud stream?

I have seen this one https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-ibm-mq but if I understand well, due to license constraints I must manually install the library (which is not possible for me).
So it will  be nice if there is a cloud stream binder all done we can declare in  our pom.xml or build.gradle (like spring-cloud-stream-kafka or  spring-cloud-stream-rabbit).

it will also be kind if someone can provide a full example  of spring cloud stream with ibm qm binder

thank you.

Comment: IBM MQ java libraries are distributed on Maven central.

Comment: I m not looking for IBM MQ java library. but the spring boot starter  that wrap this java library ...

Comment: Did you find what you are looking for, I am in the same situation. @soung

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring Cloud Stream project is currently supporting bindings only for RabbitMQ, Apache Kafka, Kafka Streams, and Amazon Kinesis. Then, there are some binders supported by partners for Google PubSub, Solace Pub/Sub+, Azure Event Hubs, and Apache RocketMQ. More info in the [official documentation](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream).

The binder for IBM MQ that you referenced is not supported anymore, just like other JMS-based systems like ApacheMQ.

The project exposes an SPI for implementing custom binders, in case you're interested. More info:

- [Implementing Custom Binders (official docs)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-custom-binder-impl)
- [How to create a Spring Cloud Stream Binder from scratch (tutorial)](https://domenicosibilio.medium.com/how-to-create-a-spring-cloud-stream-binder-from-scratch-ab8b29ee931b)